# How to change path of script tag dinamically in a jsp page using angularjs variable? (Possible duplicate)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

here is my problem:

I got a WEB project
There i have a main page, there I can open a new tab and the new tab automatically loads an external javascript file.

Now, that all works fine, and how it should, on the localhost
Once I deploy my application on my local wildFly server and run it on standalone, on a different URL (something.something/somethingSpecial)

There I have a folder on the end of the URL (it's not mine) and in my code, i would need to go a step back a the relative path in order to import my script.

Now I need an easy way to set the path of a script tag using the environment.production option (angularjs 4)

Here is the code of my JSP page of the tab:

```
//what I have
<script 
    src="rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}">
</script>

<script>
    // I send the production boolean with the link that opens the tab
    // and just split it out of it :)
    var production = location.search;
    production = production.split('&production=')[0] // this is true or false (tested, and it's 100% working)
</script>
```

Now, I need something like this:

```
<script 
    // I need to go one folder back, and do the same as above
    src="../rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}">
</script>
```

I could write just the second code, and be done with it, because, it is gonna work on the server, but then it wont work on my localhost and that I cannot have

So, I would like to have both, something like this:

```
<script 
    src=if (production) then "../rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}" else "rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}">
```

I tried something like this, but I could not get it work...

```
src={{production && '../rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}' || 
                       'rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}'}}
</script>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Script-Element. Add an Id attribute to your script element(it's totally fine).

HTML

```
<script id="script" src="rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}"></script>
```

JavaScript

```
function changeSource(production){
    var path = production ? "../rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}" : "rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}";
    document.getElementById("script").setAttribute('src', path);
}
```

**Before page load: (Angular)**

JavaScript

```
var path = production ? "../rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}" : "rest/project1/getSource/${param.userId}/${param.fileName}";
```

DOM

```
<script src="{path}"></script>
```

Comment: from where should i call the function? From the same script or? I need to load that script on page load.

Comment: Updated my answere.